# How to use multiple COUNT statements in SQL sharing the same GROUP BY?

Tags: sql, join, count

I have the following statement which outputs the correct data

```
 SELECT COUNT (Section_ID) AS Sections
 FROM Section
 GROUP BY Location;
```

And this statement which also outputs the correct data

```
 SELECT COUNT (e.Section_ID) AS Students
 FROM Section s, Enrollment e
 WHERE s.Section_ID = e.Section_ID
 GROUP BY Location;
```

However, when I put these statements together like so

```
 SELECT Location, COUNT(s.Section_ID) AS Sections, COUNT (e.Section_ID) AS Students
 FROM Section s, Enrollment e
 WHERE s.Section_ID = e.Section_ID
 GROUP BY Location;
```

Sections and Students now share the same data. How can I combine these statements together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Second, remember what `COUNT()` does.  It counts the number of non-`NULL` values.

One way to do what you want is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT Location, COUNT(DISTINCT s.Section_ID) AS Sections,
       COUNT(DIStINCT e.Student_Id) AS Students
FROM Section s JOIN
     Enrollment e
     ON s.Section_ID = e.Section_ID
GROUP BY Location;
```

I have to guess on what the primary key is for `Enrollment`.  I'm guessing `Student_ID`.

Comment: Correct, it is student_ID. Thank you so much, this fixed it perfectly.